# Getting the size of mapped files similar to RamMap in c#

Tags: c#, memory, ram

In my c# program I want to check how big the mapped files in standby are. 
My program doesn't use them, it only wants to know what the total size is.

Similar to the cell found in RamMap (Row = Mapped File; Column = Standby).

I couldn't find any Performance Counter or any c# class which might help me.
Currently I am working with the .NET Framework 4.5.2

If it isn't possible in c#, PowerShell would also be possible.

Comment: This information is not exposed in any API (public or otherwise) dealing with mapped files; RamMap probably grovels around in kernel object internals for this (and the other information it obtains). If you have access to the file mapping, though, you can use `MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor` in a simple loop that doubles offsets and then backs off again to find the size by simple probing, with no need for dipping into kernel internals.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What do you mean by If you have access to the file mapping? How can I do this?

Comment: Never mind. I meant that if you know the name of the memory-mapped file you can open it (`MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting`) and determine the size by probing the valid offsets, but of course this is 1) redundant if backed by a file since you can just get the size directly from that and 2) not actually the number of pages in standby for the memory mapping. The latter number should be available only to the kernel memory manager; I don't know how RAMMap retrieves it, but it probably involves some black, not-exactly-documented magic.